# Retrieve XAML from programmatically created UserControl at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, reflection

I'm creating a generator for UserControls in C#. It looks nearly like this:

```
UserControl control = new UserControl();
Grid contentGrid = new Grid();
control.Content = contentGrid;
//create Buttons, Labels, Bindings etc.
return control;
```

now my Question is whether I can get the XAML of the created UserControl at runtime, and if it is possible, how I can do that.

For instance from the Code above I want to retrieve Something like:

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
       ....
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`XamlWriter.Save()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlwriter.aspx) for that, but it's [limited](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754193.aspx).

Comment: Weel, I guess it would work, if my base class would not be a generic one -.-

Comment: Normal XAML doesn't really support generics, so I'm not sure how would you want to do that.

Comment: Well even if the ViewModel of the control is generic it fails.

Comment: How do you set the view model? If I just set `DataContext` to a generic class, it seems to work.

Comment: My Control has a Property ´StandardCrudViewModel<T> ViewModel´ which is the ViewModel

Comment: Yeah, that won't work, because that view model can't be represented using XAML. The only way I can think of how could this work would be if you set that property to `null` before serialization. You probably don't want to serialize that view model anyway.